# Через gulp 4.0.2 не происходит конвертация кода написанного на scss в css. Почему так?

Tags: gulp, scss, gulp4

В package.json установлены данные плагины:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1"
  }
```

В gulpfile.js написан данный код:

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const scss = require('gulp-sass');

function styles() {
return src('app/scss/style.scss')
.pipe(scss())
.pipe(dest('app/css'))
}

exports.styles = styles;
```

В bash терминале выходит такая ошибка:

```
$ gulp styles
[17:29:46] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\from0to1\start_gulp\gulpfile.js
[17:29:46] Starting 'styles'...
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:

gulp-sass no longer has a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself.
Both the "sass" and "node-sass" packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:

    const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

[17:29:46] The following tasks did not complete: styles
[17:29:46] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const gulp = require("gulp");
const scss = require("gulp-sass")(require('sass'));

function styles() {
  return src('app/scss/style.scss')
  .pipe(scss())
  .pipe(dest('app/css'))
}

exports.styles = styles;
```

Рабочий код.